# Which of the following determines an inner product over the space of real continuous functions with continuous first derivatives?

Tags: inner-products

First inner product is:

$\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^1 f'(t)g'(t)dt + f(0)g(0)$

Second inner product is:

$\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^1 f'(t)g'(t)dt$

I know that for something to be valid inner product it must have these properties

1. Hermitian symmetry $\langle x , y \rangle = \overline{ \langle x , y \rangle}$
2. Linearity1 $\langle sx, y \rangle = s \langle x, y \rangle$
3. Linearity2 $\langle x + y, z\rangle = \langle x, z \rangle + \langle y, z\rangle$
4. Positive definiteness $\langle x , x \rangle > 0$ if $x \neq 0$ and $\langle x, x\rangle = 0 \iff x = 0$

I wrote proof for the first one following all the rules but I thought it shouldn't so am I right or doing something wrong?

1. Recall $\bar \alpha = \alpha$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb R$:

$$
\begin{align}
\langle f,g\rangle &= \int_0^1 f'(t)g'(t)dt + f(0)g(0) \\
        &= \int_0^1 g'(t)f'(t)dt + g(0)f(0) \\
        &= \langle g,f \rangle
\end{align}
$$

2.

$$
\begin{align}
\langle sf,g\rangle &= \int_0^1 sf'(t)g'(t)dt + sf(0)g(0) \\
        &= s\int_0^1 f'(t)g'(t)dt + f(0)g(0)\\
        &= s\langle f,g \rangle
\end{align}
$$

3.

$$
\begin{align}
\langle f + h,g\rangle &= \int_0^1 (f+ h)'(t)g'(t)dt + (f+h)(0)g(0) \\
                 &= \int_0^1 (f' + h')(t)g'(t)dt + (f+h)(0)g(0) \\
                 &= \int_0^1 \big(f'(t)g'(t)+h'(t)g'(t)\big)dt + f(0)g(0) + h(0)g(0) \\
                 &= \int_0^1 f'(t)g'(t)dt + \int_0^1 h'(t)g'(t)dt + f(0)g(0) + h(0)g(0) \\
                 &= \int_0^1 f'(t)g'(t)dt + f(0)g(0) + \int_0^1 h'(t)g'(t)dt + h(0)g(0) \\
                 &= \langle f ,g\rangle + \langle h,g\rangle
\end{align}
$$

4. Let 0 be the function with no support on [0,1].

$$
\begin{align}
\langle 0, 0\rangle &= \int_0^1 0'(0)0'(0)dt + 0(0)0(0) \\
                    &= 0
\end{align}
$$

And for any function that has support on [0,1] (and is smooth):

$$
\begin{align}
\langle f, f\rangle &= \int_0^1 f'(0)f'(0)dt + f(0)f(0) \\
                    &= \int_0^1 f'(0)^2 + f(0)^2 \\
                    &> 0
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Looks fine to me. There's only a typo in (2.): It should say $s(\int_0^1f'(t)g'(t)dt+f(0)g(0))$, you forgot the brackets.

Comment: The first inner product is the correct one. When looking at the second inner product, for property 4, if $f = 1$ (which is in your space), then $\langle f,f \rangle = \int_0^1 0^2 dx = 0$, so $0$ is not unique. Therefore this isn't an inner product space.

Comment: @jbenoit that's what I wasn't seeing, any constant function will evaluate to zero. Thank you